# A free and open source database administration tools

Tags: java, database

I need to find a free and open source database administration tools that connects to all database engines (for sample by a `jdbc` driver). I want general task by this tools such as `add/delete/update/select` table or `create/edit/remove` tables.

Comment: Must it really be open source?

Comment: I found also `DB Solo`, it's fine. http://www.dbsolo.com/

Comment: DB Solo is neither open source nor free.

Comment: You're right but it has a freeware part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLWorkbench is my favorite: http://www.sql-workbench.net/, zero setup, runs directly from a JAR.

Comment: Thanks. Can it create/delete/edit tables graphically?

Comment: I don't think so. I never create tables this way.

Comment: Yes,it can. It's very good. I downloaded and using it. Thanks for you are sharing your knowledge with me.

Answer (score 1):

We have used [ExecuteQuery](http://executequery.org/features.jsp) in production, it is not bad. Supports all databases that have a JDBC driver. Open source, pure Java.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty satisfied with [squirrelsql](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)